# Compute the length of a module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

I'm reading my class notes of Commutative Algebra. I'm stuck on an exercise given in my notes:

**Definition:** Let $M$ be a $A$-module. If $M$ has a composition series then the length of the composition series is called the length of the module otherwise we say $M$ has infinite Length.

> **Exercise:** Let $M=\frac {m^n}{ m^{n+1}}$ where $m=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) \subset k[[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]]=A$. Compute the length of $M$.

I'm unable in finding a composition series for this module $M$? How do we "guess" composition series in general? Any hints/ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Let $(R,m,k)$ be a local ring, and $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module such that $mM=0$. Then $l(M)=\dim_kM$.

In fact, $M$ is an $R/m=k$-vector space and its submodules (as $R$-module) are the same as its subspaces (as a $k$-vector space). Since it is finitely generated it follows that $\dim_kM<\infty$, so $M$ is a module of finite length, and $l(M)=\dim_kM$ (since the composition factors have all dimension one). Furthermore, $\dim_kM$ equals the minimal number of generators of $M$. Can you find this in your case?

Comment: Sorry..I'm confused.Is there any relation between $l(M)$ as an $R$-module and $l(M)$ as an $ \frac{R}{m}$-module?

Comment: They are equal (because the submodules are the same and this follows from $mM=0$). For more details you can also have a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325825/if-m-is-an-r-module-and-i-subseteq-mathrmannm-then-m-has-the-struct

Comment: +1 I see,Thanks.But how do you count generators in this case?

Comment: @ArpitKansal They should be all the products of $n$ (not necessarily distinct) variables, that is, all the degree $n$ monomials in $x_1,\dots,x_n$.

Comment: correct,but how do we count them?

Comment: @ArpitKansal See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551214/the-number-of-monomials-of-a-given-degree